# Which question is the duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

*I'm sure I should've dug in more here at Meta to find some guidance, assurely this is a conversation that has been had frequently, but I cannot spare too much time and don't want it to go un-resolved.*

I have a question from 2011:

[How to replace replace radio buttons with images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112995/)

Which has been marked as a duplicate of a question from 2013:

[Use Image instead of radio button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17541614/use-image-instead-of-radio-button)

They *are* effectively the same question.

The newer one is doing significantly better in terms of votes, etc..., but there are pretty similar view counts, and multiple quality answers on both.

What is the best course of action here?

Comment: The age of a Q+A is irrelevant,  *Somehow* the later question got 1000% more votes than the earlier one.  Better Google juice, it isn't always obvious what keywords it selects on or what programmers query when they look for an answer.  But, clearly, Q+A that is x10 more appreciated should be the canonical one.

Comment: 29 votes vs 11 isn't really 1000% more, but point taken.

Comment: That irony on the all those duplicates here..